# _.sortBy() removing extra 0 from floating point value (converting 0.10 -> 0.1 and so on)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Below is my array which i want sorted -

```
var baseBetAmount = [
{
    val: 'OtherBaseBet',
    text: 'Other'
},
{
    val: 0.10,
    text: '$0.10'
},
{
    val: 0.20,
    text: '$0.20'
},
{
    val: 0.50,
    text: '$0.50'
},
{
    val: 1,
    text: '$1'
},
{
    val: 2,
    text: '$2'
}]
```

I am writting below fumction to sort it .

```
  var options=  _.sortBy(baseBetAmount)
```

It is returning below output  -

```
[
{
    val: 'OtherBaseBet',
    text: 'Other'
},
{
    val: 0.1,
    text: '$0.10'
},
{
    val: 0.2,
    text: '$0.20'
},
{
    val: 0.5,
    text: '$0.50'
},
{
    val: 1,
    text: '$1'
},
{
    val: 2,
    text: '$2'
}]
```

Here 0.10 is replaced by 0.1  , 0.50 by 0.5 and so on.
Can anyone please help me here , i dont want 0.10 to get replaced with 0.1 and so on

Comment: `0.50` and `0.5` are same. If you want `0.50`, try `num.toFixed(2)`

Comment: It will always be that way, since 0.1 is the same as 0.10 as a number. Only the string differs. I would advice to just use `.toFixed(2)` in the visuals on the number, to turn it into a string with 2 digits past the dot. Be mindfull to do this After any calculations. So in this case, apart from the default: `bet.text = "$" + bet.val.toFixed(2);`

Comment: But what if this array contains 0.100000 or 0.2400000

Comment: Doesn't matter. 0.1 as a number is the same as 0.1000000 so any calculations will stay the same. It's only the string that differs and with toFixed(), you can add any amount of trailing zeroes to the string representation of the number.

Comment: @Shilly Actually i dont want to change values in this array , they should be as it is, i am using those values to print somewhere else. Values should not get change with anything

Comment: The object already contains the printable value (`text`), why can't you use that for printing?

Comment: I'm not saying you have to, I'm just showing it's possible. For the record. if you're going to do calculations with the floats, like calculating prices and such, cast them to integers insead and divide by 100 again after any calcs so you don't run into floating point precision bugs. (like 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that would work, but it need to parse value when doing mathematical calculations.

```js
var baseBetAmount = [
{
    val: 'OtherBaseBet',
    text: 'Other'
},
{
    val: 0.10,
    text: '$0.10'
},
{
    val: 0.20,
    text: '$0.20'
},
{
    val: 0.50,
    text: '$0.50'
},
{
    val: 1,
    text: '$1'
},
{
    val: 2,
    text: '$2'
}];

 var options = _.sortBy(baseBetAmount).map(function(base){
  if(_.isNumber(base.val)){
   base.val = base.val.toFixed(2);
  }
  return base;
 });

console.log(options);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`toFixed()` returns a string, so you have to parse it using `parseFloat` for mathematical calculations.